# how to align textview and image view so they dont overlap each other in android ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, overlapping

can someone help me in this issue. i have listview that has textview and imageview. the text in some phones appears in top of the image view.. how can i resolve this issue

[this image shows my issue](http://postimg.org/image/q6rowx29r/)

This is layout file for this issue

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Medium Text"
         android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:maxWidth="180dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `android:toRightOf="@id/item_icon"` to your TextView called `item_name`.
So it will stay at the right side of your icon without overlapping.